# Getting Selected TTreeview Children

Tags: delphi

I am trying to get all child nodes of the selected node in a treeview but have run into a few problems.

Take this treeview as an example:

[image]

I want to get all nodes that are child to yellow highlighted "Folder" node, which would be the child nodes with a blue line next to it.

This is what I tried:

```
procedure Form1.GetTreeChilds(ANode: TTreenode);
begin
  while ANode <> nil do
  begin
    ListBox1.Items.Add(ANode.Text);
    ANode := ANode.GetNext;
  end;
end;
```

It works except that it also returns Item 6 which is not child to the yellow highlighted "Folder".

What do I need to change or do differently to only get the child nodes to the yellow highligted Folder?

Thanks.

Comment: WAD. Why aren't you using GetFirstChild, etc?

Comment: @MartynA I guess I overlooked it :( Remy Lebeau's answer is exactly what I was looking for though.

Comment: Good.  Fwiw, TTreeview + its nodes are so widely used that if one's code isn't working, it's a fairly sure sign that the code is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
procedure Form1.GetTreeChilds(ANode: TTreeNode);
begin
  ANode := ANode.GetFirstChild;
  if ANode = nil then Exit;
  ListBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    repeat
      ListBox1.Items.Add(ANode.Text);
      GetTreeChilds(ANode);
      ANode := ANode.GetNextSibling;
    until ANode = nil;
  finally
    ListBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! Aside from missing GetFirstChild as pointed out by MartynA, you used the Recursive magic I also failed to try and used GetNextSibling.

Comment: I would personally avoid locking (here `BeginUpdate`, `EndUpdate` pair) inside a recursive procedure. It's wasting of time.

Comment: @TLama you are right, in fact I only had the Listbox.Items.Add for testing purposes, Remy probably expanded on his answer and included it to further help - but I already know about stopping the UI updating with `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate`.

Comment: @TLama: Begin/EndUpdate are reference counted, only the first BeginUpdate will disable drawing, and the last EndUpdate will re-enable it, the rest of the calls just increment/decrement the update counter.  It is a good idea to use Begin/EndUpdate when making multiple Add (or remove) operations, it helps improve performance.

Comment: @Remy, I know how they work. I just would not use them inside a recursive function. That's what a caller of this function should do, IMHO.