# Select all child from a Node in treeview

Tags: delphi

What is the problem with the below code. Its going in an infinite loop

```
for Itr := TreeView1.Items.Count-1 downto 0 do Begin
  if TreeView1.Items[Itr].Selected then
  begin
     Node := TreeView1.Items[Itr];
     if (Node.Level = 0) and Node.HasChildren then begin
     Sel_Node := Node.getNextSibling;
       while Assigned(Sel_Node) do
       begin
          Sel_Node.Selected := True;
          Sel_Node := Node.getNextSibling;
       end;
     end;
  End;
End;
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the infinite loop is in the two lines marked;

```
  if (Node.Level = 0) and Node.HasChildren then
  begin
    Sel_Node := Node.getNextSibling;  // here
    while Assigned(Sel_Node) do
    begin
      Sel_Node.Selected := True;
      Sel_Node := Node.getNextSibling; // and here
    end;
  end;
```

The node `Node` stays the same on every iteration, therefore the node `Sel_Node` is also the same on every iteration and the condition `Assigned(Sel_Node)` never becomes false. Maybe you intended to write

```
      Sel_Node := Sel_Node.getNextSibling;
```

within the `while` loop?

Since the header of this question says "Select all child from a Node in treeview" I wonder why you are getting the sibling nodes only and not child nodes also? It's not really clear what you try to achieve.

You may want to refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27463281/getting-selected-ttreeview-children?rq=1) for an example of how to recursively traverse through the nodes.

---

Edit after comments:

With `TreeView1` properties `MultiSelect = True` and `MultiSelectStyle = [msControlSelect]` and applying the recursive search for children and siblings I linked to, the code to select all children under an already selected node with `level = 0`, looks f.ex. like this:

```
procedure TForm1.SelectChildren(ANode: TTreeNode);
begin
  ANode := ANode.GetFirstChild;
  if ANode = nil then Exit;
  repeat
    TreeView1.Select(ANode, [ssCtrl]);
    SelectChildren(ANode);
    ANode := ANode.getNextSibling;
  until ANode = nil;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Node: TTreeNode;
begin
  if (TreeView1.Selected <> nil) and
     (TreeView1.Selected.Level <> 0) then Exit;
  Node := TreeView1.Selected;
  SelectChildren(Node);
end;
```

Comment: I want to select all child from a perticular node programatically

Comment: I believe I answered your question "*What is the problem with the below code. Its going in an infinite loop*". I also provided a link to an example of how to recursively find all children of a treenode.

Comment: That was my next question though:) fixed the infinite thing but the multiselect wasnt happening

Comment: @siddharthtaunk I edited my answer with sample of selecting all children of a node, using the `Select()` procedure.

Comment: @siddarth We aren't here to offer ongoing support as you do your work. We are here to answer the specific question that you asked.